# Why is the residue of $f(z)=\cot(z)-\frac{1}{z}$ at $z=n\pi$ is different via diffrent approaches?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What is the residue of $f(z)=\cot(z)-\frac{1}{z}$?

Solution:\since $f$ has a simple pole at $z=n\pi,then $$$Res[f(z),n\pi]=\lim_{z\to n\pi}(z-n\pi)(\cot(z)-\frac{1}{z})=\lim_{z\to n\pi}(z-n\pi)\cot(z)-\lim_{z\to n\pi}\frac{z-n\pi}{z}$$

$$\implies Res[f(z),n\pi]=\lim_{z\to n\pi}\frac{(z-n\pi)\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}-0$$

By.L'hopital's rule,

> $$Res[f(z),n\pi]=\lim_{z\to
>  n\pi}\frac{\cos(z)-(z-n\pi)\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}=\frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^n}=1$$.

Now,we'll make use of the following  theorem to find $Res[f(z),n\pi]$-

> An isloated \singular point $z_0$ of a function $f$ is a pole of order
>   $m$ iff $f$ can be written in the form 
>   $$f(z)=\frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$$ Where $\phi(z)$ is analytic and
>   non-zero at $z_0$.Moreover,
>
> $Res[f(z),z_0]=\phi(z_0), $if $m=1$ &
>
> $Res[f(z),z_0]=\frac{\phi^{(m-1)}(z_0)}{(m-1)!} $if $m\geq 2$

Here,$f(z)=\cot(z)-\frac{1}{z}=\frac{z \cos(z)-\sin(z)}{z \sin(z)}$,$m=1$.So,

> $$Res[f(z),n\pi]=\frac{n\pi \cos(n\pi)-\sin(n\pi)}{z}=\frac{n\pi
>  (-1)^n}{n\pi}=(-1)^n$$

Comment: In the second approach, how do you apply the theorem exactly? And what happened to $\sin z$ in the denominator of the function?

Comment: @Did:actually,second appraoach is applicable only if  the denominator of $f$ have polynomial function,but i did'nt  get  it during problem solving.

Comment: Not sure this answers my comment. Anyway, since your question was to understand how methods A and B are giving different answers, now we know that this is because B is unsound. Right?

Comment: @Did:I wrongly applied the formula in second method,for the application of this formula there should be some  terms like $(z-z_0)^i$,but is not so with my question as in the denominator,it is $sin z$.

Comment: Right. Reformulating my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a simple pole at $n\pi$, for $n\ne0$, because
$$
\lim_{z\to n\pi}(z-n\pi)f(z)=
\lim_{w\to0}wf(w+n\pi)=
\lim_{w\to0}\left(w\cot w-\frac{w}{w+n\pi}\right)=1
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z\cos z-\sin z}{z\sin z}=
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z-z^3/2-z+z^3/6+o(z^3)}{z^2+o(z^2)}=0
$$
so at $0$ the function has a removable singularity (which becomes a zero of order $1$).